# How to Exclude sass files from ng-build?

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

I use sass-loader in webpack.config to compile scss files to one bundled minified CSS file and I will manually reference this file in my "Index.html" but i need to exclude scss files from "ng build", I excluded it in `tsconfig.app` 
`"exclude": ["../**/*.scss"]` but it didn't work.

Comment: Just don't reference it anywhere and you should be good.

Comment: (Assuming that you use angular CLI)

Comment: @trichetriche sorry don't get your comment .. what do you mean with don't reference it ? and yes i am using CLI

Comment: In your components, in the decorator, you can see a `styleUrl` property. Your excluded file should not appear in any of them. In your angular cli file, you have a `styles` array, it should not be there too. Basically, remove any reference of your file from your code

Comment: @trichetriche I tried it and also didn't work but even if it works, i won't able to see my styles during development

Comment: You want to see your styles, but not use it ?

Comment: while development i will use sass files and modify it, but when i want to publish build, i will use `ng-build` or webpack command to compile them and minify them to `.css files`, but till now i still see `.scss` files in dist folder

Comment: Then it's because you didn't referenced them, they should be compiled in your dist. Add them to your angular-cli.json file.

Comment: @trichetriche i think i was misunderstand thing, I wasn't know that ng-build compile scss for me as i wasn't see any css files, only .js files, i see now that cli converts everything to Js, Is that a way to convert styles files (.scss, .less) to css not js or this is a new trend for web now ??

Comment: Well it's the point of the "bundlers" like webpack or systemJS. If you don't want to use them, don't use angular CLI ! but why would you see your CSS files ? Maybe I can provide you with another solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148585/discussion-between-ahmed-ragheb-and-trichetriche).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Angular CLI, you are in for it to handle all these sorts of things for you. You are not expected to handle them yourself. The CLI intentionally does not expose a build-tool-specific extension point (although an idea of a CLI plugin system is one of the things on the table for v2).

One thing you can do though is use the `ng eject` command to extract the Webpack config and customize it yourself. Read more about this option [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-moving-out-of-the-cli).

**Update:**

Based on comments, it looks like this question is motivated by how the CSS is applied via JS in Angular CLI by default.

If this is the case, please note that this is configurable via the `ng build` flag `--extract-css`. If set, the build generates a CSS file not JS file for the CSS. The flag is off by default in dev mode (default `ng build` / `ng serve`), and on by default in production mode (when you pass the `-prod` flag).

Learn more from [the official `ng build` docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).

Comment: thanks for your answer, now if I even depends on CLI, it converts all my scss files to js bundlee files but it also keeps the global ones (the ones I defined in styles tag in CLI.json) after build, so I will end up with unnecessary and unused files in server (.scss)

Comment: Also do you recommend to depend on CLI or eject my project and modify build, did you face any problem (performance, debugging) during your work with the idea of convert style files to js files.

Comment: I suggest you just use what the CLI gives. There's no problem in CSS done via JS, but also in production mode the CLI makes a CSS file anyway. It doesn't do it in dev mode because it increases build time, but there's a flag for it `--extract-css`. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: I tried your comments and it works but till now still .scss files appears in build, specially files that i defined in global styles tag in angulatcli.json, i tried exclude but didn't work, I open bug for that but i don't know if it is a valid bug or not
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6906

Comment: There should not be SCSS files, unless you define them in `assets` ( instead of `styles`) in `.angular-cli.json`. Try a simple project `ng new test --style=scss`, `cd test`, `ng build -prod`, and then check the `dist` folder.